# JavaScript querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

A tutorial I'm working on has the following code with the following comment. I don't understand...

i) the comment, specifically, why it says "all second table cells."  What does "second" mean? This isn`t proper English

ii) what is it looking for exactly when it says `td + td`? The program is about taking data from a table, so would `td + td` pick out anything between html table tags `<td></td>` for example?

```
//use querySelector to find all second table cells
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("td + td");
```

Comment: Perhaps the second level of tds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's looking for only `<td>`s which are preceded by another `<td>` ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors ).

So with this HTML, it would match `<td>`s 2-4 (inclusive):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tMrbA/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a selector `foo + bar`, it will search for an element `foo` and then select all elements matching `bar` which are siblings coming after `foo` and have the same parent as `foo`.